# Audio Output level metering in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, core-audio

I am developing an iPhone game with cocos2d,
I have used CDAudioManager for playing sound(this is why because i have to change the pitch of  output sound). I want to measure the output sounds power. Not the gain.
I know about peakpowerForChannel: for avAudioplayer. But it can't be used here because I want to change the pitch of o/p sound. Is there any method like this for CDAudioEngine

Thank you